# Serverless Unknown service "plugin"

Tags: serverless

I'm trying to install a plugin for my serverless project, and I ran into this error in the headline.

Also received this variant: `Command "plugin" doesn't exist`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
This was because I ran with `serverless-compose` from a parent directory.
In order to install the plugin, you have to be in the directory of the actual serverless.yml file.

```
cd my-service
serverless plugin install my-plugin
```